# get/retrieve the value/data-attribute of the selected option from dropdown in office ui fabric core

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-fabric

I am adding the option list using jquery to my drop-down and my option looks like this

```
    <option value="7f8a19e6-18b8-47e4-b60f-bd8a4880a224">10-city health club</option>
```

I want to retrieve the "value" of the option that I have selected from the drop-down.

the selected option and the list look like this:

```
<span class="ms-Dropdown-title">abc</span>

<ul class="ms-Dropdown-items">
<li class="ms-Dropdown-item">Select Project</li>
<li class="ms-Dropdown-item">abc</li>
<li class="ms-Dropdown-item">10-city health club</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This seems to be a JavaScript/HTML question that doesn't have much connection to office-js or add-ins in particular. I suggest that you change your tags to something that's a better match to what you are asking.

Comment: @RickKirkham This is actually a question related to office js because when we make dropdowns using fabric UI, the span and the list field are made on their own using the office js and I have not much control over them.

Comment: @RickKirkham My issue is that I need to get the value or data attribute of <option> field which is very well achieved using normal javascript and HTML. However, In case of fabric js, I am not getting the data attributes in the list or in the selected option which is in the span field making it difficult for me to retrieve the attributes of the selected option.

Comment: I've added the `office-fabric` tag to your question. Perhaps this will get the attention of knowledgeable people.

Answer (score 1):

we can get the selected option value as

```
 var id = $('#idOfTheSelectTag :selected').attr('value');
```